# Updating a Current CoreData Store

Tags: objective-c, core-data

How would you update a CoreData store with a new/updated data model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [data migration](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmMigrationProcess.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005508-SW1):

> During migration, Core Data creates
>   two stacks, one for the source store
>   and one for the destination store.
>   Core Data then fetches objects from
>   the source stack and inserts the
>   appropriate corresponding objects into
>   the destination stack. Note that Core
>   Data must re-create objects in the new
>   stack.

Comment: Does the same apply to the mac?

Comment: Yes. Core Data is the same on the iPhone and the Mac with the exception that the iPhone does not currently support Cocoa-bindings.

Comment: Yes.  Core Data is nearly identical between the two platforms.